# checked checkboxes don't override hidden input with the same name

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a table form whose rows can be generated dynamically.
Each row has two text inputs and a checkbox.

And also a hidden input with the same name as checkbox.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="names[]" class="form-control" required="required"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="rates[]" class="form-control" required="required"></td>
    <td><input class="simple" type="checkbox" name='disallow_flag[]' value='1'/><input type="hidden" name="disallow_flag[]" value="0"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

$("#add_row").click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    html    =
            '<tr><td><input class="form-control" name="names[]" type="text" required="required"></td>\n\
            <td><input class="form-control" name="rates[]" type="number" required="required"></td>\n\
            <td><input class="simple" type="checkbox" name="disallow_flag[]" value="1"/><input type="hidden" name="disallow_flag[]" value="0"></td>\n\
            <td><a href="#" class="item_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td></tr>';
    $(".menu_update_table").append(html);
});
```

After creating few rows and checking few checkboxes, I get the following output:

```
'names' => array(3)
 "dfdf"
 "sdfds"
 "dsfds"
'rates' => array(3)
 "1"
 "2"
 "3"
'disallow_flag' => array(4)
 "0"
 "1"
 "0"
 "0"
```

Note that disallow_flag array has four elements; since I have checked only one box out of three.

Expected output:

```
'disallow_flag' => array(3)
 "0"
 "1"
 "0"
```

How do I override hidden checkbox value if the corresponding checkbox is checked?

Comment: Only by removing or disabling that hidden field dynamically …

Comment: @Jeff not true at all. Every browser sends all those parameters; one that didn’t could only be considered defective. (PHP however has the specific quirk of overwriting parameters of the same name with the last value when parsing this received data, unless [] are used in the name.)

Comment: @CBroe ah, ok. I knew the symtoms of having twice the same name and expected it's the browser...sorry, I'll delete that comment then.